# TbsSQL MSSQL compatible with PHP 7

Tags: php, sql-server, tinybutstrong

I've been using TBS, OpenTBS and TbsSQL for several years now, always on PHP 5.3.x.  I recently decided to try an upgrade to PHP 7.0, and have now run into a strange problem (an error, apparently, but not error text coming back, just:

[TbsSql][Error]: Database error message:

Has anyone else successfully used TbsSQL with SQL Server (the tbssql_sqlserver_odbc.php module, last updated in 2010) in PHP 7?

Is there some known reason why this might not work?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, so I'll post what I found just in case someone else ran into this weird situation.

I'd apparently had a minor bug in my original code that was doing a $Db->Close() call before I was really done with the connection.

For some reason, in my old environment (where the only difference I think was that I was running a pre PHP 7 version (5.3 or maybe 5.6, possibly it behaves the same on both of those)), subsequent calls using the same $Db connection would succeed, even though, technically, it should've been closed.

As I said, I was using the tbssql_sqlserver_odbc.php module.

Anyway, in PHP 7, once I removed that incorrect Close call, my modules worked as they should.

It's probably a weird obscure situation, but maybe it'll help some one else out someday.

Further note: the symptom I was getting (which is probably generally true of TbsSQL calls, I suppose) is that a call to (e.g.) GetRow would return false instead of an array with the results, as usual.